# Swiper iDangero.us: Fire events when a specific slide is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, swiper.js

I'm trying to hide certain divs when slide 2 and 4 are active, but the code doesn't seem to work.

Elements to hide:

```
<div id="element1">
   <h1 class="title">Title #1</h1>
</div>

<div id="element2">
    <h1 class="title">Title #2</h1>
</div>
```

Slider's code:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide slide1"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide slide2"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide slide3"></div>
        <div class="swiper-slide slide4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        ...,
        on: {
        init: function () {
        if (slideActiveClass.is('.slide2 .slide4')) {
        $(".title").addClass("hidden");
        } else {
        $(".title").removeClass("hidden");  
            }
          }
          }
    });
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
    }
```